# How to handle datatable of jquery when has no records

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have create a datatable, but it cannot handle that the database table is empty. It keep showing "Processing...". I have check that the json return null. so how can i handle datatable when json is null?

PHP

```
$returnJson["data"][] = null;
```

jquery:

```
var table =  $('#Table').DataTable({
                   "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]]
                    ,"processing": true
                    ,"serverSide": false
                    ,"ajax": "<?=url?>"
                    ,"language": {
                        "zeroRecords": ""
                        ,"emptyTable":     "My Custom Message On Empty Table"
                    }
              });
```

Comment: Show us your code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found it. The PHP should be like as the below:

PHP

```
if($table_result == null)
{
    $returnJson["data"] = array();
}
```